# Repository module code completely different from downloaded file

Tags: version-control, community-official-site

Using the Drupal Soundmanager2 module that hasn't been updated in about three years. Added a little functionality and want to submit a patch.

I think this can be [done via git](https://www.drupal.org/node/707484):

```
git clone --branch master http://git.drupal.org/project/soundmanager2.git
```

but the files shown [in the tree](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/soundmanager2/tree/soundmanager2.module?id=0034fdbfb77548682be95270e29d7da571a384ec) that are in the download zip file are completely different from what's in the git repository.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the master branch is still pointing to an old (probably obsolete) branch. To get the latest version, which is inline with the zip file you downloaded, you should use:

`git clone --branch 7.x-2.x http://git.drupal.org/project/soundmanager2.git`

Maybe you should open an issue and point them to the [Moving from a master to a major version branch](https://www.drupal.org/empty-git-master) documentation.

Comment: Looking back through my terminal history, I think the problem may have been caused by me cloning without the flags: `git clone git@bitbucket.org:frob/drupalforfirebug.git`.

Comment: @MikeiLL At the time of writing this comment, the Git repository of the Soundmanager2 (Drupal) module is not inline with the Drupal conventions. So I think it still a good idea to open an issue to point the maintainer to the 'Moving from a master to a major version branch' documentation (https://www.drupal.org/empty-git-master).

Comment: Oh I have, man. It looks like it's been a while since was maintained.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Hadn't checked the issue queue... hopefully the maintainers are reactivated again ;)

Comment: What happens if they don't respond for a while?

Comment: You could ask to be a maintainer (if you want to), see https://www.drupal.org/node/251466